# Arrays não iniciados em C

Tags: c, array, char

Como saber quanto devo colocar  de tamanho para percorrer um array não iniciado []? 
Por exemplo nesse com char[].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

   char texto[] = "Linguagem C.";
   /* for(int i=0; i<13; i++) {
    printf("%c", texto[i]); 
   } */

}
```

Sem precisar contar os elementos de um array, vetor, como saber? em um array(vazio)
E também o que significa o caractere "\0", porque no livro que estou lendo ele diz que a string texto terá 13 de tamanho, mas "Linguagem C" tem só 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa contar os caracteres! Basta saber que a string termina em '\0' e utilizar tal condição em algum loop. Talvez esse seja um dos motivos que o string em C termine em '\0'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char texto[] = "Linguagem C.";
   int i = 0;  

   while(texto[i] != '\0'){

       printf("%c", texto[i]); 
       i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Toda string em C deve terminar com '\0'. Quando você escreve `char texto[] = "Linguagem C.";` o compilador automaticamente coloca um '\0' no final de sua string.

Não fique a toa contando caracteres na tela:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char texto[] = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting";
    int i = 0;  

    while(texto[i] != '\0'){

       printf("%c", texto[i]); 
       i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Já pensou ?

Comment: Agora entendi..

Answer (score 4):

Em C, todas as *strings* têm um terminador nulo, que é o caratecere '`\0`' no final da *string*. Este caractere também ocupa memória, e por causa disso, ele faz parte da *string* e deve haver espaço reservado para ele no *array* de caracteres.

O caractere '`\0`' nada mais é do que o valor zero representado como um caractere (ver na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)). Em C, as *strings* o utilizam para representar aonde a *string* termina.

Desta forma a *string* "`Linguagem C.`" têm 12 caracteres, mas contando com o terminador '`\0`' serão 13, portanto será necessário um *array* com 13 posições para armazenar esta *string*.

No C, há a função [`strlen`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) que dá o comprimento de uma *string* sem contar com o terminador nulo. Mas atenção que esta função computa o tamanho da *string* ao percorrer todos os seus caracteres um a um procurando pelo terminador nulo, então se a sua *string* for muito grande (um livro inteiro, por exemplo), ela será lenta, e portanto é melhor evitar usá-la se você puder obter o tamanho da *string* de alguma outra forma mais eficiente.

E como apontado pelo Jonny Piazzi em um comentário, uma vez que o `strlen` apenas procura pelo terminador nulo, o tamanho do *array* em si não interessa. Desta forma se você usar um *array* de 20 caracteres para armazenar uma *string* com apenas 12, o que vai importar será a posição aonde o terminador nulo será encontrado.

Comment: Além disso tenha em mente que strlen computa o tamanho de sua string válida. Se você tiver uma string de 12 caracteres dentro de um array de char de 20 posições ainda assim strlen retornará 12.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Obrigado, complementei o meu texto com esse seu comentário. :)

Comment: Vou ver essa strlen quando estudar strings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok você fez várias perguntas.

> Como saber quanto devo colocar de tamanho para percorrer um array não iniciado []?

Resposta, sempre que você não estiver trabalhando com um array dinamicamente alocado.

> Sem precisar contar os elementos de um array, vetor, como saber?

Existe em outras linguagens, mais comumente em linguagens gerenciadas (ex java, c#) jeitos de descobrir o tamanho de um array, mas em C isso é complicado e dependendo do cenário pode ser impossível.

> E também o que significa o caractere "\0"?

O caractere '\0' é o caractere "fechador" de uma string. É como você assinala onde deve ser parado de ler a cadeia de caracteres.

Você fez muitas perguntas em uma única, por isso minha resposta foi muito vaga. Sugiro que você desmanche sua pergunta em perguntas únicas e poste cada uma individualmente assim podemos responder cada uma com mais detalhes.

Comment: Ok, mas criar várias perguntas seria ruim, não??

Comment: Não se a pergunta for consistente. Tenha em mente que sua pergunta não é só para você, ela está publica para outras pessoas que um dia passarão pelo mesmo problema que você. Mas ficará bem mais difícil para estas pessoas acharem o que procuram se tem várias perguntas em uma mesma, pode ser que o problema dela seja só com o caractere `\0` por exemplo, mas ela não queira saber sobre comprimento da string.

Comment: Não havia pensando nisso.