# Lixo na memoria ao imprimir vetor de trás para frente

Tags: array, c++

> 02 - Crie um algoritmo que solicite que o usuário entre com o seu nome e armazene em um vetor,
>    o programa deverá armazenar em outro vetor o nome escrito de tráz para frente. 
>    Ao final, deverá ser escrito os dois vetores. Ex.: vinicius - suiciniv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

main(){

    char vetor[10];
    cout << "Digite um nome:";
    cin >>vetor;
    vetor[strlen(vetor)] = '\0';
    char contrario[strlen(vetor)];
    int tamanho =strlen(vetor-1);

    int j=0;

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(vetor);i++){

        cout<<vetor[i];

    } 


    for(int i=strlen(vetor)-1;i>=0;i--){
        //cout <<vetor[i];
        contrario[j] = vetor[i];
        j+=1;
    } 
    cout<< "--" <<contrario;

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Precisa terminar com o caracter nulo o vetor de caracteres `contrario`. A propóstio, o próprio `cin` vai colocar o terminador nulo, você não precisa colocá-lo na mão após a leitura.

Comment: Voce pode editar o código por favor? para que eu possa compreender melhor. estou iniciando em c++, e a minha primeira linguagem de programação .. n entendo mt coisa ainda

Comment: Sobre terminador nulo, você pode encontrar diversas resposta aqui no StackOverflow em português sobre o assunto. Por exemplo, [esta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64360/64969) me parece ser bem intuitiva e está bem escrita. Não vou editar seu código porque não faz sentido no seu aprendizado, você deveria entender os conceitos que falo e, não os entendendo, ir atrás do significado deles.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui resolver esse problema utilizando string e getline.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main (){
 
 string palavra;
 cout << "Digite a Palavra:";
 getline(cin,palavra);
 for (int i=0;i<palavra.size();i++){
  cout <<palavra[i];
  
 }
 cout <<endl;
 
 for(int i=palavra.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
  cout<<palavra[i];
 }
 
 
 
 return 0;
}